# Making a request response queue with Azure Java SDK

Tags: java, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm trying to implement something similar to https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Brokered-Messaging-Request-0ce8fcaf#content in Java, but can't find functionality from the Service Bus Java SDK to match the `QueueClient.AcceptMessageSession` used in the example.

So how can I make the client to poll the response queue only for messages that match the expected sessionId? Do I need to create a seperate response queue for each client? Or is it best practise to re-insert non matching messages back to the queue?

I'm using the `com.microsoft.azure/azure-servicebus` maven package version `0.9.3`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this feature is not supported in the Java SDK because it uses the service bus REST api instead of the WFC api. Topic/Subscription way might be the only way to implement this with the Java SDK.

More detail: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/246

Answer (score 0):

@HannuHuhtanen, in my mind, I think the solution is that using two JMS connections to seperately connect two service bus queues for a continuous WebJob as server and clients, please try to refer to the [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-java-how-to-use-amqp/) to know how to use JMS with AMQP for ServiceBus.